# How to encode german ,french charcter into C# using amazon email service

Tags: c#

Eg,Oliver Angermüller is displayed as Oliver AngermÃ¼ller in header part of email.

Can you please given any suggestion regarding this?

```
mailMessage.Subject = subject;
```

The issue only arise in the header part of mail.

Comment: What did you do to ensure that your subject variable indeed holds the correct text? Weighting the chances of Amazon having codepage problems using UNICODE against the chance that a random guy on the internet has codepage problems in his program reading that data from somewhere... I guess the chances of a bug in Amazon software are pretty slim.

Comment: hello i searched in google but i cannot able to find the solution for this.How to encode this?

Comment: @Preethy: Make sure you use the correct text encoding (UTF8 vs windows-1251, ISO-8859-1 (latin1), …)

Comment: Can you please explain this UTF8 vs windows-1251,ISO-8859-1

Comment: How do you get `subject`, where does its information come from? If you google 'C# UTF8' there are many links explaining what knittl said

Comment: subject is the header part of email,there Name is displayed incorrectly